# I encrypt data by symmetric key in SQL server. How to decrypt by C#

Tags: c#, encryption

Data stored in an MS SQL server is encrypted using AES128, which is a symmetric key algorithm.

How do I decrypt this data in C# if I know the password?

Comment: Reworded question so that what is needed is clearer.  Also added C# tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a stored procedure which will decrypt the key and return your result. Let you have encrypted a column named "SSN" in your table named "YOUR_TABLE" with password "YOUR_PASSWORD". To return the decrypted SSN this stored procedure will work fine:

```
DECLARE @SymKeyPwd VARCHAR(50) = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'

DECLARE @open nvarchar(200)
SET @open = 'OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Sym_ssn DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Cert_Password WITH PASSWORD = ' + quotename(@SymKeyPwd,'''') + ';';

SELECT (CAST(DECRYPTBYKEY(SSN) as nvarchar(MAX) FROM YOUR_TABLE

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.openkeys
    WHERE key_name = 'Sym_ssn'
    )
BEGIN
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY Sym_ssn
END
```

Call the above SP from your c# code and get the desired result.

Comment: Hey?? May I know the above answer is working or not for you. It will help other people also.

Comment: You have assigned a string containing  the open key statement and the needed password to variable `@open` but you are not executing the statement.