# SQL Server Symmetric Key - Key Derivation Algorithm

Tags: sql-server, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to use an application external to SQL Server to decrypt data (that I've) encrypted in Azure SQL Database. I can decrypt it natively in SQL Server using [DecryptByKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decryptbykey-transact-sql) - but I want to do this on the client computer. I know the *key_source* parameter used to generate the key and I can decode the initialisation vector and cipher data from the field data thanks to [this SO post](https://superuser.com/questions/1261329/what-is-iv-in-symetric-encryption-in-mssql).

The key is being created by:

```
create symmetric key #tempkey
  with algorithm = AES_256,
  key_source='*****'
  encryption by password = '*****'
```

I'm not able to find a reference to the key-derivation algorithm used by SQL server to convert the key_source into
the actual key. [Sqlity](https://sqlity.net/en/2492/identical-symmetric-key/) says that the details are not published, however this blog article is getting old now - and I'm hoping that's changed.

Inspecting the key information in *sys.key_encryptions*:

```
key_id|thumbprint|crypt_type|crypt_type_desc|crypt_property
259|NULL|ESP2|ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD V2|NULL
```

*sys.symmetric_keys* doesn't appear to yield anything of use

There is [a similar SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837336/i-encrypt-data-by-symmetric-key-in-sql-server-how-to-decrypt-by-c-sharp); but the answer refers to using a stored procedure to complete the decryption - which is not what I want to do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of the key derivation algorithm implementation so that given the known key_source, I can generate the symmetric encryption key value and decrypt the cipher data?

My work-around is to do both encryption and decryption outside of SQL Server, but I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: For client-side encryption/decryption, consider [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) instead.

Comment: @DanGuzman, different groups of rows are to be encrypted with different keys - which I think rules out Always Encrypted as an approach.